# tensorflow works in anaconda console, fails in notebook with:.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

following the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) to install tensorflow using anaconda seems to work as:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
```

prints out hello. but the same code in a notebook gets:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-25b92e4d5dec> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
      3 sess = tf.Session()
      4 print(sess.run(hello))

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

i started the notebook with jupyter notebook in the acaconda prompt that said:

```
(tensorflow) D:\ray\dev\ml\mit>
```

in one of my user directories.

starting jupyter notebook from the windows start menu fails also.

what is the correct way to start jupyter notebook?

Comment: What is the result of `import sys \n print(sys.executable)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, activate the anaconda environment which you have `tensorflow` installed. Then

```
conda install nb_conda
```

Still in that environment, run `jupyter notebook`